# Mobile: Physics and movement actions

Tags: physics, cocos2d, cross-platform, spritekit

I've been using spritekit for a while for a few small games. One thing I've noticed is that spritekit is the first game framework I've used that allows me to apply move actions to physics bodies. (without anything screwing up at least.)

Are there any cross platform game frameworks I can use that allow move actions on physics bodies? Not impulses. I've used cocos2d in the past and when I tried ccmoveby on physics bodies the simulation would get totally confused. I rather not use cocos2d anyway.

I'm asking because I want to make cross platform games and spritekit is iOS only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpriteKit or Kobold Kit and then use Apportable to convert it to Android.

http://www.apportable.com/

But if you want truly cross compatible you could use Unity3d free version and build out to the specific platform you want since iOS and Android are given. (They now have 2D Sprite abilities)

It costs a pretty penny if you want the Pro features though.
http://unity3d.com

Comment: Unity for the win!